# RobotFramework Browser library installation failed ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: robotframework

I Tryed to install Robotframework browser (win10 enviroment).

Nodejs installation goes ok.  But in "pip install robotframework-browser" After this step installation exits with statuscode 1:

Installing collected packages: grpcio, wrapt, typing-extensions, robotframework-pythonlibcore, robotframework-assertion-engine, overrides, grpcio-tools, backports.cached-property, robotframework-browser
Running setup.py install for grpcio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h6_hezr8\grpcio_55999491d4194df7ab59a8dcd0fe4e6e\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h6_hezr8\grpcio_55999491d4194df7ab59a8dcd0fe4e6e\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-agotwqfa\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\grpcio' Check the logs for full command output.

Any ideas how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Check if the library is compatible with Python 3.10.
Try a lower version of Python.